# Exit a deadlock cycle

Tags: deadlocks

[image: deadlock cycle]

Suppose i have the following resource allocation graph with a deadlock cycle, i see why it is a deadlock cycle, what i don't get is how to recover from this cycle

i'm thinking about aborting a process, any process here will lead to non-deadlock situation, but doesn't that cause the other process to not execute and hence the program won't execute as we're expecting it to be, i think this is a correct answer, but is there another way to do such that all processes will eventually run ?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t exit a deadlock cycle. Once you are in a deadlock situation, you lost. You do your best to avoid deadlocks.

With server software, you may be able to have a process that watches other processes and kills them if they are stuck due to a deadlock. Doing this *correctly* and make your software continue to run correctly is extremely difficult. It’s so difficult that i wouldn’t even try. In addition it is an absolute pain to test (and you don’t want software that isn’t tested). For normal software running in anything from workstation to mobile phone, it’s just not done. Remember that you have two tasks that are trying to do something and one or both of them have to be killed, that is hard to recover from.

What you do in practice: 1. Instead of locking a mutex you check if it is lockable which avoids deadlocks. 2. You add code that detects situations where a deadlock is *possible*. And if you find a *possible* deadlock you fix your code. 3. Write sensible code in the first place.

Comment: Note: breaking free of the deadlock isn't that hard, but it comes with a price: you may violate things that are otherwise invariant.  This can be a big deal in many applications.  For example, some of the classic banking applications can execute half of a transfer, crediting one account but failing to debt the other, or vice versa.  Proving that this sort of behavior is acceptable is what is so difficult to do right.

Comment: In databases, deadlocks are routine, and the solution is to abort or (partially) rollback a transaction.